# Ruby global scope

Tags: ruby, scope

When answering another question, I realized that the following program does not quite do what I thought it does.

```
puts "test"
self.puts "test"  # => private method `puts' called for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

The exception surprises me, as I always thought that top-level method calls would be resolved by the `main` object instance, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Who's the actual receiver of the first call and how is it resolved? Is this a special rule that only applies to method calls at the top-level scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [good discussion](http://ruby.11.n6.nabble.com/Kernel-s-module-methods-td3405875.html) that talks about this question.

The top level methods, which are provided by [Kernel](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html), are automatically included to the *Object* class. This means the Kernel methods will appear in everything.

The error `private method 'puts' called for main:Object (NoMethodError)` is just stating that puts exists but is privately scoped.

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :001 > puts "test"
test
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :004 > self.send(:puts, "hi" )
hi
```

**UPDATE**

There is no magic for Kernel methods. There is no scope hopping or anything. I think the confusion lines in what the scope is when using `self`. You do not have access to private methods using `self`.

```
class PutsTest

  def success_puts
    private_puts
  end

  def failed_puts
    # trying to access a private method from self
    self.private_puts
  end

  private

  def private_puts
   puts 'hi'
  end
end
```

By using *self*, you are changing the scope from calling the method inside of *PutsTest* to calling from the outside of *PutsTest*

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :095 > test = PutsTest.new
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :096 > test.success_puts
hi
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :097 > test.failed_puts
NoMethodError: private method `private_puts' called for #<PutsTest:0xd62c48>
```

Comment: Yeah, but why can I call a private method if I don't specifiy `self`?

Comment: Because puts on its own is scoped inside of the Object, directly calling self.put means you are trying to call the put method scoped private to self. Ill update my answer with some code . .

Comment: Hopefully the code example helps illustrate puts vs self.puts

Comment: Absolutely, so it was all due to my failed understanding of how `private` works :)

Comment: Now that I thought about it, it's more my failed understanding of `self`. It's actually very consistent in that it is treated just like any other object reference.

Comment: Exactly. I stumbled over this as well when I learned Ruby. Coming from a Java background, I expected `self` to behave like Java's `this`.

Comment: Fun thing is that I am using Ruby for several years now and this issue never crossed my ways...

Comment: @NiklasB.: Because that's the definition of `private`: "can only be called without an explicit receiver." (Well, except for setters, which *have* to be called with an explicit receiver, since otherwise there is a syntactic ambiguity with local variable assignments.)

Comment: @JörgWMittag: Yes, I guess that it's the special treatment of `self` for private setters that always made me think that `self` would allow access to private methods.